# Accidentally nuked my Rails installation - what do I need to do to recover?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I seem to have broken my Rails installation on Mac OS 10.6.7.  Here's the status:

```
MacBook-Pro$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
MacBook-Pro$ which gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
MacBook-Pro$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
MacBook-Pro$ gem -v
1.8.5
```

I use homebrew to manage these packages:

```
MacBook-Pro$ brew list
distribute  libyaml     ossp-uuid   python      sqlite
gdbm        mongodb     pip     readline    wget
git     mysql       postgresql  ruby
```

My ~/.profile has this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Before this ordeal started, I used

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I just ran it again and got this:

```
MacBook-Pro$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Successfully installed rails-3.0.9
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.9...
file 'lib' not found
```

But when I run:

```
which rails
```

I get nothing in return.

I think at some point I went into /usr/bin/ which is I think the "which rails" pointed to in order to see what was in the rails file.  And I think I may have deleted this file.  (Yes, I'm an idiot.)

**It looks like I somehow need to connect the location of the rails gem with the OS so that it knows it's there?  Or can/should I nuke the whole installation?**  I'd appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a good time to switch to using rvm.

https://rvm.io

Comment: Thanks, this worked in the end!  I had to try 'gem install rails' twice, but it's all set up now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with gem install with -V option, maybe you'll see where it's installing everything.  It installs rails for me in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.9/bin/rails and /usr/bin/rails.  It's hacky but you could copy rails from the first location to the second if it doesn't automatically add for you.  Best idea is probably to nuke it and start fresh.